# Why isn't c++ offered as a code-behind language for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c++, code-behind

I was curious why C++ isn't offered as a code-behind language for ASP.NET applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested, here's some interesting articles about how you could use managed C++ as your code-behind:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/helloworldmc.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301369.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Most ASP.NET applications run in limited trust modes. And C++ generally compiles into something that requires higher trust levels.

Answer (score 3):

C++ *is* supported, but as another answer says - most C++ apps require a higher level trust mode that **ASP.NET cannot support**. You ***can***, however, use C++ to **create assemblies and web component**s that can then be consumed by ASP.NET & IIS.

[There is a project to include C++ as a code-behind language.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/helloworldmc.aspx)

[Article on creating consumable assemblies](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301369.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the answer. However for hardcore c++ guys who want to develop ASP.NET apps in C++, you can always build your core logic etc in a separate project/assembly. You can't run away from VB.NET or C# totally though.